# from livecd find the installed kernel version on ht hard disk

Tags: kernel

my ubuntu is not booting. the recovery mode also has a problem. when machine boots it says Ubuntu Linux 2.6.32-37 server but boot does not work. I tried using ubuntu 10.4 LTS version iso and tried to boot from livecd. How to find out which version of OS is installed on my machine from livecd. I am getting kernal panic not syncing attempted to kill init! error. How to solve this problem. Pl. suggest which livecd to use and how to solve this kernel panic error.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it less ambiguous. From reading your question, it seems like you get your kernel panic message when you try to boot to the server on the hard disk and NOT when you boot to the Ubuntu 10.04 live CD, or maybe this is not what you meant. Your question is not 100% clear, so please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to mount your ubuntu partition and `chroot`

Run below commands AS ROOT

```
mount /dev/ -rw /mnt/ubuntu
chroot /mnt/ubuntu
uname -a
```